# short line in top right article titlepage using \maketitle

Tags: titles

is it possible to have something like

```
\rightline{some short text}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\maketitle
```

without causing \maketitle to start a newpage, i.e. to have a short text placed top right on the title page, using standard article in latex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to have to redo the whole formatting of the tilte page by hand, you can use  the `titling` package. It defines 4 hooks for the `\maketitle` command, so that (extracted from the `titling`doc), titling's `\maketitle` is:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\vspace*{\droptitle}
\maketitlehooka
{\pretitle \title \posttitle}
\maketitlehookb
{\preauthor \author \postauthor}
\maketitlehookc
{\predate \date \postdate}
\maketitlehookd
 }%
```

So you could add to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\hrulefill some short text
\vspace{0.2cm}}
```

Likewise, `\maketitlehookd`,  lets you add things at the bottom of the title page. As for `\droptitle`, it is a length that allows adjustment of the vertical positioning of the title.

Answer (score 1):

use the environment `titlepage`  instead of the macro `\titlepage`:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\hrulefill some short text

\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{center}
  \huge my title 

...
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```